# How to align x-axis scale on two concatenated graphs in Vega Lite

Tags: vega-lite

I have a chart composed with `vconcat` and `layer`. The layered plot is one of the blocks in the vertical concatenation, it plots two different datasets. There are two more blocks in the vconcat: one that has a different (third) dataset, and another that is a smaller version of one of the layers (used for brushing / zoom). The x scales of all the charts follow the selection via brush signal; the bottom chart sets the signal value via user interaction.

[image]

I would like to align the x-axes on all the vconcat chunks. The dataset of the mis-aligned one does not cover as much as the timeseries line (it starts and ends around where the vertical dashed lines are).

When zooming / brushing with the bottom chart, the axes align. When the chart first loads, each x-axis covers the extent of the matching dataset. I'd like the axes to cover the largest extent of all the layers / concat blocks.

I've tried using the resolve config, "shared" vs "independent" etc, with no success.

Comment: Please include code that demonstrates the problem; preferably a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without that it is unlikely that your question will get any useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but a hack to get the desired result. An accepted answer should be a vega-lite config solution.

I modified the mis-matched dataset to have the same first and last timestamp, which causes the scales to naturally align.

[image]